# Learn JD Edwards tools as BA

Tags: business-logic, jde

It would be great if someone have help me. My I am a BA/BPM. I have business knowledge but no coding experience in general programming languages. For my benefit and ease, I normally get the basic of the technology the company uses, like DB2, Oracle etc. My company is planning something with JD Edwards for which I am not working but interested in learning. I do not have any exposure to it.

What is the best way to approach this. I have seen several versions on Oracle website. 
- In terms of which version I can download to get familiar with it (Lower is better to learn, but if there are major changes in structure or something that I need to keep in mind).
- Which would be a good book/documentation as a beginner esp. end user and business end. 
- who is the best way to do 
Eg. for cognos I had single machine installation, created a table in data base to right till I published reports to get overview of how things work. And once I have overview, Business/ Logical is where my work mainly dwells and so this is where I spend most of the time playinge.

I know this is long, but a pointer in the right direction would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

JD Edwards is not a database like DB2 or Oracle.  It is a large ERP (Enterprise Resource Planning) application with a TON of different modules and configurations.  It would be nearly impossible for you to accomplish any useful learning with a local install.  I would recommend asking within your department for access to the company's development environment and for some walkthroughs on the modules that your company uses.